# Java NetBeans connecting to MS Access Database Error

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

That's my program:
[image: This picture shows the whole program. Please see this link. Thank you!]

Cannot Connect. Details below. Please help me! Thanks!

**This is my code in "Java Class" (Connect)**

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Connect {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rst = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;

public static Connection ConnectDB(){
try{Class.forName ("sun.jbdc.odbc.JbdcOdbcDriver");

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)}; DBQ = Data.mdb");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected");
return conn;
}catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not connected");
return null;
}
}
}
```

**While this are my code in "NewJFrame"**

In this NewJFrame. I used the import java.sql.*; and connection conn to connect it from the "public static Connection ConnectDB()" from the "Java Class (Connect)". I just used a event that is WindowedOpen to atleast try if its connected. But sad to say. Its not. Please help me! Hoping for good and easy to understand answers.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn = null;

public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

 private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
   conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
    }        

public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Instead of just showing "not connected", how about printing a stack trace? The important issue is what the error is exactly.

Comment: Also, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm planning to connect it to Java NetBeans. I'm just a beginner in NetBeans. I think the error is that I cannot connect my MS Database to NetBeans. Do you have any idea sir on how I can connect my database? I really don't know what to do. Stack trace. I don't have the slightest idea. :'(

Comment: Its 6.9. My teacher said the we will use this version of Java NetBeans.

Comment: You are supposed to do an `e.printStackTrace()` inside your catch in order to get a stack trace and add it to the question. Also, I was asking about the version of *Java*, not the version of NetBeans - NetBeans is just an IDE and is irrelevant to the whole issue.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm sorry sir. Its Java(TM) 6 Update 45.

Answer (score 1):

First Try to correct your coding

**Number 1**

```
try{Class.forName ("sun.jbdc.odbc.JbdcOdbcDriver");
```

to

```
try{Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

then when the above still does not work try to path the MS Access
**Number 2**
From

```
DBQ = Data.mdb
```

to

```
DBQ = 'path'/Data.mdb
```

Ex.: path = 'D:\DB\MSAccess\' + Data.mdb | D:\DB\MSAccess\Data.mdb